# Как сделать финальную ячейку в UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, separator

Доброго времени суток.
Интересует вопрос: Как в UITableView сделать финальную ячейку как в приложении "Контакты" с подсчетом строк?

Таблица создана через `PrototypeCells`.
Кода практически нет. Отображается только 1 лейбл на строку.

В моем представлении нужно создать отдельный прототип ячейки и убрать у него `separator`. Однако получается только убрать сепаратор следующей ячейки, а все за ней снова с разделителями.

В `CellRowAt`:

```
if indexPath.row == self.converterItems.count-1 {
            cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, cell.bounds.size.width, 0, 0)}
```

Comment: Используйте для этих целей footer в UITableView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте `tableviewFooter`:

```
let footer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 50))

let label = UILabel(frame: tableViewFooter.bounds)
label.text = "Your's text"
label.textAlignment = .center

footer.addSubview(label)

tableView.tableFooterView = footer
```

Comment: А можно ли как то добавить верхний сепаратор для футера?

Comment: Используйте grouped tableview. Там по умолчанию есть сепаратор для футера.

Comment: Grouped tableview слишком простое решение. Плюс хотелось бы реализовать именно через такой способ. Ваш код работает, правда я попробовал UIView на UITableViewCell заменить, но сепаратор не появился. Наверное потому что это футер

Comment: Вы можете нарисовать линию шириной в 1 пиксель, и сделать ее сепаратором, но сепаратор в таблице меньше чем 1 пиксель, поэтому повторить его не получится. А чем Вам не подходит слишком простое решение? Зато оно универсально, не зависит от девайся, от разрешения экрана, от ориентации экрана.

Comment: Я сделал функцию для футера и его высоту сделал пол пункта, как у разделителей в таблице. Ну и по цвету сделал таким же